# How to replace last occurrence of substring in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to replace only the last occurrence of a substring with another substring. For example for only the last occurrence of `x:y` I want to replace it with `r:w`

Example:

`There {x:y} is a {x:y},u bench` -> `There {x:y} is a {r:w},u bench`

I could only find a parameter in `regex_replace` that would replace the first occurrence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("There {x:y} is a {x:y},u bench");
  std::regex e ("x:y"); 
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"r:w",std::regex_constants::format_first_only);
  return 0;
}
```

Is there an efficient way to replace the last occurrence instead of the first?

Comment: Is it a fixed substring or do you require it to be a pattern?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe For now I want to know how to do it for a fixed string then I would look into how to do it for a pattern

Comment: [`std::string::rfind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind).

Answer (score 0):

Until someone proposes a better solution, `replace_last` is what I found from `boost`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>



    int main()
    {
      std::string s= "There {x:y} is a {x:y},u bench";
      std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
      boost::algorithm::replace_last(s,"{x:y}","{r:w}");
      std::cout<<s<<std::endl<<std::endl;
     
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse your input string, the regex and the replacement and then replace the first occurance:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("There {x:y} is a {x:y},u bench");
  std::string pattern = "x:y";
  std::string replacement = "r:w";

  std::string out = s;
  std::regex_replace (
    out.rbegin(),
    s.rbegin(),
    s.rend(),
    std::regex (pattern.rbegin(), pattern.rend()),
    std::string(replacement.rbegin(), replacement.rend()),
    std::regex_constants::format_first_only
  );
  std::cout << out << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

```
There {x:y} is a {r:w},u bench
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YEWGj5sbn

You can even do it in-place, without creating a copy of `s`: https://godbolt.org/z/P98z9s7v8